# Are there general techniques to avoid stack overflow by using promises?

Tags: javascript, promise, es6-promise

I found that one way to do it is by "doing it later" once in a while:

```js
function knowNFactorial(n) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    n = BigInt(n);

    if (n === 1n) {
      resolve(1n);
    } else {
      if (n % 1000n !== 0n) {
        knowNFactorial(n - 1n).then(v => resolve(n * v));
      } else {
        // just "do it later" once in a while
        setTimeout(() => {
          knowNFactorial(n - 1n).then(v => resolve(n * v));
        }, 0)
      }
    }
  });
}

knowNFactorial(20000).then(v => console.log("I know its binary representation length is", v.toString(2).length));

// Only do the following inside of Node or Google Chrome developer console:
// knowNFactorial(20000).then(v => console.log("I know it is", v));
```

But are there other general techniques or studies about this?  For sure, we don't have to use recursion to solve `factorial(n)`, but if there are problems that requires recursion and if stack overflow might happen, looks like there is one technique of: before any possibility of stack overflow, just create that promise some other time (and come out of the recursion).

Only print out the whole result inside of Node or Google Chrome. If it is done inside of the snippet, it doesn't work so well. (probably the `body` to contain the big number with no wrap is way too wide and using a lot of memory):

```
knowNFactorial(20000).then(v => console.log("I know it is", v));
```

Otherwise, one way is just to convert it to binary and print out the result's length of digits, as in the snippet.

If it is a regular recursion of `factorial(n)`, typically it'd stack overflow on my Node or Google Chrome when `n` is over about `12,000` or if it is over `20,000`. I just tried the code above with `n` being `100,000` and it wasn't a problem.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206031/discussion-on-question-by-nopole-are-there-general-techniques-to-avoid-stack-ove).

Answer (score 1):

To compute recursively the factorial but avoid the maximum call stack size we can use:

- some microtasks

  `process.nextTick( _ => f(...))` / `Promise.then(_ => f(...))` or `Promise.finally(_ => f(...))` / `queueTask(_ => f(...))`

(with `process.nextTick` for Node and `queueTask` for browser)

- some delayed macrotasks

  `setImmediate` or `setTimeout` or even `setInterval`

(with `setImmediate` for Node)

- the same execution context

  via *trampolining* which does not stack recursively

---

Perf wise by faster to slower

- if possible make it non recursive
- trampolining
- then microtasks
- then macrotasks (likely because you make an event loop each time)

```js
function nextTick (n, s, cbk) {
  if (n === 1n) {
    return cbk(s)
  }
  return process.nextTick(() => nextTick(n - 1n, s * n, cbk))
}

function pthen (n, s = 1n) {
  if (n === 1n) {
    return s
  }
  return Promise.resolve().then(() => pthen(n - 1n, s * n))
}

function pfinally (n, s, cbk) {
  if (n === 1n) {
    return cbk(s)
  }
  // Promise.finally does not return the value and you don't want to use
  // .then (since already covered), so return value by callback
  return Promise.resolve().finally(() => pfinally(n - 1n, s * n, cbk))
}

function microtask (n, s, cbk) {
  if (n === 1n) {
    return cbk(s)
  }
  return queueMicrotask(() => microtask(n - 1n, s * n, cbk))
}

function immediate (n, s, cbk) {
  if (n === 1n) {
    return cbk(s)
  }
  return setImmediate(() => immediate(n - 1n, s * n, cbk))
}

function timeout (n, s, cbk) {
  if (n === 1n) {
    return cbk(s)
  }
  return setTimeout(() => timeout(n - 1n, s * n, cbk), 0)
}

function interval (n, s, cbk) {
  // feels like trampolining but letting the engine call us back instead of doing it explicitely
  arg1 = n
  arg2 = s
  const id = setInterval( function () {
    if (arg1 === 1n) {
      clearInterval(id)
      return cbk(arg2)
    }
    arg2 = arg1 * arg2
    arg1 = arg1 - 1n
  }, 0.01)
}
function tco(n, s = 1n) {
  if (n === 1n) {
    return s
  }
  return tco(n - 1n, s * n)
}
function trampoMain (n) {
  function trampo (n, v = 1n) {
    if (n === 1n) {
      return v
    }
    return _ => trampo(n - 1n, n * v)
  }
  let f = trampo(n)
  while (typeof f === 'function') {
    f = f()
  }
  return f
}

function cbkToProm (f) {
  return n => new Promise((resolve, reject) => f(n, 1n, resolve))
}

;(async _ => {
  const methods = {
    pthen,
    pfinally: cbkToProm(pfinally),
    trampolining: trampoMain
  }
  if (typeof process === 'object') {
    methods.nextTick = cbkToProm(nextTick)
  }
  if (typeof setImmediate === 'function') {
    methods.setImmediate = cbkToProm(immediate)
  }
  if (typeof queueMicrotask === 'function') {
    methods.queueMicrotask = cbkToProm(microtask)
  }
  // horribly slow
  methods.setTimout = cbkToProm(timeout)
  methods.setInterval = cbkToProm(interval)

  // does not work
  methods.tco = tco

  const N = BigInt(1e9)+7n
  for (const [name, f] of Object.entries(methods)) {
    console.time(name)
    console.log('res', parseInt((await f(2000n)) % N))
    console.timeEnd(name)
  }
})()
```

A side node about tco (for tail call optimization), I wondered whether we would magically avoid the maximum call stack size but does not seem to come soon ([ptc syntax at draft 0](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-ptc-syntax))

Comment: at the current moment I do not know if these are opinions or based on some common practices  or standard practices... can you cite some references or posts?

Comment: I don't think this is neither common nor standard practice since for huge recursion one would likely go the iterative way. In case of non perf critical stuff, one would use macro task to avoid [io starving](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/event-loop-timers-and-nexttick/). Still I don't have links and this post was just created looking at what are [microtasks](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_DOM_API/Microtask_guide)